# Modificar cadena de conexion de mi DbContext en entity framework en tiempo de ejecucion .net 6.0

Tags: asp.net, api, .net, entity-framework, inyeccion-de-dependencias

como estan? Estoy trabajando con .NET 6 para generar una api la cual consta de listar productos pero dependiendo la url que me llegue al controlador como parametro voy a establecer la cadena de mi conexion al db context, mi db context ya esta agregado por defecto al IServiceCollection, hay alguna forma de hacer que se modifique esa cadena de conexion ya asignada al IServiceCollection, o de reemplazarla por alguna nueva donde establezca la conexion a partir de la URL que como habia dicho anteriormente me llega por parametro?

Para mostrar el caso que estoy intentando resolver el parametro URL lo voy a definir yo en el mismo metodo.

Aqui va mi codigo:

```
using Infrastructure.EntityFramework.Contexts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net;

namespace API_StoreSysBackendCustomers.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IGetConnectionString _getConnectionString;

    public ProductController(IGetConnectionString getConnectionString)
    {
        _getConnectionString = getConnectionString;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetCustomers")]
    /*ESTO ES PARA UNICAMENTE LOS USUARIOS AUTORIZADOS [Authorize]*/
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IReadOnlyList<Product>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IReadOnlyList<Product>>> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        var URL = "MI URL DE PRUEBA QUE LLEGA POR PARAMETRO";
        string connectionString = _getConnectionString.GetConnectionString(URL);

        //ACA QUIERO CAMBIAR LA CONEXION DE MI DB CONTEXT CON LA VARIABLE "connectionString " QUE OBTUVE A TRAVES DE LA INFTERFAZ _getConnectionString, EXISTE ALGUNA FORMA DE HACERLO?


        var result = (await ServiceLocator.GetService<ProductSearcher>().GetAllAsync()).ToList();
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

ServiceLocator.cs:

```
public static class ServiceLocator
{
    private static IServiceProvider? provider;
    public static IServiceProvider Provider
    {
        set => provider = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(provider));
        get
        {
            if (provider == null) throw new Exception("Provider no inicializado");
            return provider;
        }
    }

    public static T GetService<T>() where T : notnull
    {
        return Provider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

        var app = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        ServiceProvider = app.Services;
        ServiceLocator.Provider = ServiceProvider;
        app.Run();

    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
            webBuilder =>
            webBuilder
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }


        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapGet("/test", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("va...");
            });
        });
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
        });

        services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
        services.AddApplicationServices();
        services.AddInfrastructureServices(Configuration);

    }
}
```

ApplicationServices.cs

```
public static class ApplicationServices
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<ProductSearcher>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

InfrasturctureServices.cs

```
public static class InfrastructureServiceRegistration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configurations)
    {

        /*String ConnectionString = configurations.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<StoreCustomersContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseMySql(
                ConnectionString,
                ServerVersion.AutoDetect(ConnectionString)
            )
            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
        });*/

        String connectionString = configurations.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<StoreCustomersContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseMySql(
                connectionString,
                ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)
            )
            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
        }); 

        services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, MySQLProductRepository>();
        return services;
    }
}
```

ServiceLocator, tiene inyectado a traves de dependencias el "StoreCustomersContext", lo que yo quisiera hacer , es en cada controlador cuando me llega la url, o bien cambiar la cadena de conexion de ese "StoreCustomersContext", o eliminar este "StoreCustomersContext" y creaer uno nuevo con la nueva cadena de conexion que obtengo a partir de la url que me llega

Espero haber sido claro y que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias !

Comment: Quieres cambiar el connection string para siempre o solo para esa función?

Comment: Hola @Yussef gracias por responder, quiero cambiar el connection string por cada vez que se ejecute ese controller, es decir se llama a la API desde una URL base, y en otra base de datos yo tengo alojado mis clientes con la URL, obtengo la cadena de conexino del cliente desde esa URL y quiero setear la nueva cadena de conexion al db context, me explico?

Comment: Seria que, dependiendo de la url que me llegue, accedo a mi base de datos y al encontrar un cliente con esa URL, devuelvo la cadena de conexion de ese cliente, y en ese momento quiero cambiar la cadena de conexion del db context con la cadena de conexion devuelta desde mi base de datos

Comment: @Yussef Ahi modifique la consulta, espero haber sido claro, gracias! (:

Comment: tengo que implementar algo parecido... conseguiste solucionarlo?